# I want to refer a parameter inside a parameter in power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, kql, adx

I have 3 adx tables named country and state and sales.
Now i want to create sale visual  in power BI based on country and state. I wanted to create a Country and state parameters, State parameter should be selected based on Country value selected. I am using below query to generate values for state list.

sales
|where country in '"&countryParam&"',
|distinct state

in the above query i want to use

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamic M parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters) to do what you propose.  But it would probably be better and easier to Import your dimension tables, and only have your fact table in DirectQuery mode.

If you don't have a proper dimension table, import a query like

```
sales 
| extend id=strcat(country,'|',state)
| distinct country, state
```

And adding a StateId calculated column to your fact table using the [COMBINEVALUES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/combinevalues-function-dax) function, which DirectQuery understands how to decompose into individual query predicates.

> when COMBINEVALUES is used to create calculated columns in order to build a relationship that joins multiple columns from two DirectQuery tables, an optimized join condition is generated at query time.